# I’m trying to move nurse and arms dealer together but I can’t select them

Tags: terraria-console

I press RT on the NPC’s but they won’t select the NPC, I’ve literally checked everything and nothing works, it worked the first time I made my world but now it doesn’t.

Comment: What version of the game are you on? When did you last do it?

Comment: I play on Xbox one